# navigating iframe from a url

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a page that pulls up information based on an ID from the url using php get. It does this in an iframe. So there is an iframe on the main page that shows all the content, if a user wants a link, they click a link to a page, which is targeted to that iframe. So if a user wants to see an individual post, the iframe is directed to a page that pulls the id from the link.

```
href="location.php/?id=2" target="mainframe"
```

My question is, I want someone to be able to click a link to my website from somewhere else, and be able to see just that post, I want to do this without having to create another page, so if there is a way to make a http://www link navigate to my page, and then tell the iframe what to do, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: nevermind, I just figured it out using php and if. Pretty simple, stupid question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this at the bottom of your page before the `</body>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById('frame_name_goes_here').src = "http://linktoyourpost.html";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used php to decide if the Id was present in the url, if it is, direct to the specified id, otherwise, the iframe source is the default page.